# Is it possible add tinyInteger or smallInteger to increments on laravel ORM?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is possible to add that code or something like that to **laravel\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint** to use with migrations?

```
public function incrementsTiny($column)
{
   return $this->unsignedTinyInteger($column, true);
}

public function incrementsSmall($column)
{
   return $this->unsignedSmallInteger($column, true);
}
```

scenario: some temp table that don't grow high and have some useful information or just small table that do not have more than 100 lines and need some rare update (add or just change). But it is possible to add to the framework? Its common to have a lot information, but sometimes sometables dont have a lot of data.

Because for increments just have the option for integer or bigInteger

Comment: It certainly is possible. Just go to the source code, see how other data types are created and add your methods, perhaps by inheriting the Blueprint class. But is it really necessary? Will you benefit a significant, tangible change for the effort? Or perhaps suggest that to Taylor on github.

Comment: Taylor said this change is not important to him. I think this should be an options to use with eloquent. But I will not discuss with him and others why need to have, i forkwed the project on github. I think Eloquent is a good tool, but not complete like many others ORM. I know the people behind ORM want to provide DB portability and its a kind of hell to maintain everything working. I like laravel, but want some fine ajustments. I think people change the app more than change the database, this is why i prefer to optimize the database to a specific DB than provide portability.

Comment: I agree with you bruno; the only thing I would add up to your solution is that it would be better to inherit the `Blueprint` class in a separate directory outside the `vendors` folder so that it does not get overwritten if you ever update with composer.

Answer (score 14):

You can use something like:

```
$table->tinyInteger('id')->unsigned()->autoIncrement();
```

Answer (score 0):

**1º**

Navigate to: laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema

Open: **Blueprint.php**

Find:

```
public function increments($column)
    {
        return $this->unsignedInteger($column, true);
    }
```

Add after this:

```
     /**
     * Create a new auto-incrementing tiny integer column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
     */
    public function incrementsTinyInteger($column)
    {
        return $this->unsignedTinyInteger($column, true);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new auto-incrementing small integer column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
     */
    public function incrementsSmallInteger($column)
    {
        return $this->unsignedSmallInteger($column, true);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new auto-incrementing medium integer column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
     */
    public function incrementsMediumInteger($column)
    {
        return $this->unsignedMediumInteger($column, true);
    }
```

Find:

```
public function unsignedInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false)
    {
        return $this->integer($column, $autoIncrement, true);
    }
```

Add after this:

```
     /**
     * Create a new unsigned tiny integer column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @param  bool  $autoIncrement
     * @param  bool  $unsigned
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
     */
    public function unsignedTinyInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false)
    {
        return $this->tinyInteger($column, $autoIncrement, true);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new unsigned small integer column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @param  bool  $autoIncrement
     * @param  bool  $unsigned
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
     */
    public function unsignedSmallInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false)
    {
        return $this->smallInteger($column, $autoIncrement, true);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new unsigned medium integer column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @param  bool  $autoIncrement
     * @param  bool  $unsigned
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
     */
    public function unsignedMediumInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false)
    {
        return $this->mediumInteger($column, $autoIncrement, true);
    }
```

**2º**

Navigate to: laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/**Grammars**

Open: **MySqlGrammar.php**

Find: `protected $serials = array('bigInteger', 'integer');`

Change to: `protected $serials = array('bigInteger', 'integer', 'tinyInteger', 'smallInteger', 'mediumInteger');`

**3º**

plus, in the same file above, find:

```
protected function typeTinyInteger(Fluent $column)
    {
        return 'tinyint(1)';
    }
```

Change to:

```
protected function typeTinyInteger(Fluent $column)
    {
        return 'tinyint';
    }
```

If someone know how to extend this files and config the usage in laravel, and want to share the how-to i will apreciate. But I dont know how to config everthing after extend these files and this is the way i know how to do this in laravel.

Comment: I think it will be better to add these code as addons instead of editing the original files. Do you know how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->tinyInteger('id', true, true);
```

You can see tinyInteger function definition in  Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint.php:

```
/**
 * Create a new tiny integer (1-byte) column on the table.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  bool  $autoIncrement
 * @param  bool  $unsigned
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
 */
public function tinyInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
{
    return $this->addColumn('tinyInteger', $column, compact('autoIncrement', 'unsigned'));
}
```

So you just set the 2nd and 3rd parameters to **true** and you get unsigned autoIncrement not null primary key.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a `tinyIncrements` method on the `Blueprint` class:

`$table->tinyIncrements('id');` should do the trick :)