# Laravel 5.4: Error with migrations and foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Having used the appropriate `artisan` commands:

`php artisan make:model VenuesGeoNations --migration`

... and:

`php artisan make:model VenuesGeoRegions --migration`

I created the schema:

```
Schema::create('venues_geo_nations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('nation');
    $table->string('iso');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

... and:

```
Schema::create('venues_geo_regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('towns_cities');
    $table->string('regions');
    $table->string('nations');
    $table->mediumInteger('venues_geo_nation_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('venues_geo_nation_id')->references('id')->on('venues_geo_nations');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

However, when I run the `migration` command, I get the error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint...

... on the `venues_geo_regions` table, in spite of the correct execution order.

I've also tried executing in the reverse order and I get the same error.

Compounding things is the fact that each `rollback` wipes out the tables for [Voyager](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager), and if it wasn't for snapshots on the EC2 instance I'm using, I'd have gone mad before now.

At this stage I'm a bit lost, and have to assume I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I think it's because `venues_geo_nations.id` is a integer meanwhile `venues_geo_regions.venues_geo_nation_id` is a mediumint

Comment: @cbaconnier, I've always used `MEDIUMINT` for the table ID, so this was force of habit. I'll give it a go...

Comment: I didn't tested, but you should be able to do an autoincrement `MEDIUMINT` like this: `$table->mediumInteger('id')->unsigned()->autoIncrement();` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761613/8068675)

Comment: @cbaconnier, scribble that up as answer and I'll chose it.

Comment: @cbaconnier, would it not auto increment by default?